# MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer failing to create database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to use EF code first migrations to build a database if it doesn't exist.  So far, I've `Enabled-Migrations` successfully.  I've also used `Add-Migrations` to make an initial migration that builds the database.  The script is in the Migrations direction and looks correct.

This is the body of my Main method

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, Configuration>());
var directConfigContext = new MyDbContext();
```

Everything I've read that says this is all I need. `MyDbContext` is in `app.config` and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DbConfig;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Additionally, if I use the DbMigrator class provided by EF, the database is built correctly (presumably using the initial database migration script).

```
// This is how it actually works including creating the database if it doesn't exist.
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
dbMigrator.Update();
```

From what I understand, setting the initializer on `MyDbContext` and afterward instantiating that `DbContext` should create the database to the latest migration... what am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instantiating a DbContext does not execute the initializer bound to it.  Instead, you need to either update the database or call the initializer on the underlying database directly.

```
MyDbContext.MyEntity.Add(new MyEntity { Name = "Nelson" });
// Or
MyDb.Context.Database.Initialize(true); // force the initialization
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer will solve the problem for other people, but I was having this same problem with a different reason: I deleted my database and modified the model by changing some classes in my `DbContext`.

When I ran my application, and it instanced and tried to use the `DbContext` for the first time, the database was not created because the last migration didn't reflect the last changes I'd made in the `DbContext`. To solve the problem I simply added a new migration by running the `Add-Migration` command on the Package manager console, and the next time the application started the database was correctly created and sed.